# Logical operators using egrep

Tags: linux, grep

How do I make use of complex logical operations with egrep?

I can simply do, "egrep -v C abc.txt"  to implement not of C and find that in abc.txt.

I can do "egrep A.*B abc.txt" to implement and of A and C to find that in abc.txt.

But how do I do something like,

A AND B (NOT C)

I googled around but couldn't find a working solution.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to pipe the output of one `grep` into the input of another:

```
egrep A.*B <file> | egrep -v C
```

Mind you, that's more of "A then B" than it is "A and B". If you need more sophisticated matching logic I suggest you check out `awk`.

Comment: Why don't you suggest `egrep A <file> | egrep B`?

Comment: Thank you. That works. I'll accept your answer. It's asking me to wait for 3 minutes :)

Comment: @Sylar: Note that this answer is also faulty... It wouldn't match something like `BwhatevA`, although this matches A and B, but not C.

Comment: Yeah, I can look at the positional restrictions myself. I just needed to know how to incorporate NOT in it. Thanks :)

Comment: As noted in the answer, it's "A then B". That was part of his original query, and I was just pointing out that it wasn't exactly as he described.

Answer (score 1):

> I can do "egrep A.*B abc.txt" to implement and of A and C to find that
>   in abc.txt.

1- your command has nothing to do with "C", it may be a typo.

2- "A.*B" is not A and B either. e.g. String "BfooA" is also A and B, but will not be matched with your regex.

A and B (not C) could be transalted to :

```
egrep A abc.txt|egrep B|egrep -v C
```

Comment: A.*B is A AND B but with positional restrictions.  And as I wrote in another comment, and FatalError and Niklas pointed out, that answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple solution:**

`A AND B` could look like `cat file | egrep A | egrep B`.

`A AND B (NOT C)` could look like `cat file | egrep A | egrep B| egrep -v C`.

**Solution using regex:**
`A AND B` means that we are "grepping" lines contains `A` and `B`. So we can present it as `(A.*B|B.*A)` and use that pattern in single `egrep` call like `egrep (A.*B|B.*A) file`.

Comment: You examples in fact only execute the last command (`B`, `NOT C`, respectively). Correct would be: `cat file | egrep A | egrep B | egrep -v C`. `cat file` can be replaced by anything that writes data to STDOUT.

Comment: I tried this thing but it wasn't giving me the correct solution. 

I wrote this command and it in output it gave me a file containing just "D F". 

This matches the criterion for NOT C but it doesn't have A and B in it